# Convert varchar from sql to byte Array

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, pdf

I have an Database, which contains some pdfs.
Im just reciving the string which is displayed by the sql Managment tool and have to create a pdf from the string, to do this I found this snipped on stackoverflow:

```
    Dim varbinary As String = DirectCast(input, String)
    Dim bytes As List(Of Byte) = New List(Of Byte)
    Dim hexpart As String = varbinary.Substring(2)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While i * 2 + 2 < hexpart.Length
        Dim hexnum As String = hexpart.Substring(i * 2, 2)
        bytes.Add(CByte(System.Convert.ToInt32(hexnum, 16)))
        i = i + 1
    End While
    Return bytes.ToArray()
```

In the most cases everything is allright but sometimes I recive an broken pdf.
It seem that it's caused by an odd Length of the varbinary string.

Comment: you know that most databases can store binary data directly, right? `varbinary(max)` in sql server, for example. And yes: an "odd" length in a hex string probably tells you that the data is corrupt. How and where: we can't guess. You could *try* adding a `0` at the start, but there is no guarantee that this is the error.

Comment: If the data actually *is* `varbinary`, then: you don't need to do anything - it will be fetched from the database as binary

Comment: Yes of course, but the thing I need to do is open the db in the sql server management studio copy the data and paste it to the tool, which should create the pdf.

Comment: and what does `datalength(thecolumn)` report for that row? an odd number? or an even number? Does it match the data you copied? Are you aware that by default SSMS truncates the text by default? (Options->Query Results->SQL Server etc)

Comment: The datalength of the column is 26435 and the on of hexpart.Length is 43677
I incrased the Lengeth of the text to the maximum

Comment: and what **exactly** is the data type? if it is `varchar(max)` and x2 hex-encoded, then: there's a problem in the data. If it is `varbinary(max)` it should be fine, and the question becomes "what is the length of the string you copied/pasted?" (it should be twice that, so 52870)

Comment: So the datatype displayed by ssms is "image"

Comment: that's fine; a bit "old school" (image is officially deprecated, and has been since sql-server 2005), but should work; fine; and how long is the string you copied, in characters? it should be 2 x `datalength(thecolumn)`

Comment: You could convert your while to a "For index As Integer = 2 To hexpart.Length-1 Step + 2" and instead of ToInt32 just use ToByte

Comment: The copied string has an lentgth of 43679 characters